# Communication between android menubar fragment and another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I have a menubar activity and some fragment in that. In one of the fragments I have a button that opened mapactivity and shows current location. My question is 
how to go to motel fragment in map activity.

I use this code in map activity but it does not work??

```
    Motel motel = new Motel();

    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = new Motel();
    if(fragment != null ){
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = 
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.maps, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

What can i do now???????
pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments can communicate with an activity that is running with an intent or an interface. Intent is the easier one if you are new to programming I think. Send an intent with a specific tag and have your activity register a broadcast receiver and catch that intent. Plenty of examples in SO of that. A fragment cannot communicate with an activity that's onPause. Exchanging information between activities can be done by sending a bundle.

Comment: hi<br/> i dont want to send any data to that fragment , i want just go to that fragment but idont know how can id that??????????????